# How to use socket.io with mean.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, mean-stack, mean.io

I am using mean.io v 0.4.0 and trying to setup socket.io with it. I want to socket.io to listen to the nodejs server. There is a post talking about it's setup [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23590005/how-to-use-socket-io-with-the-latest-mean-io) but it doesn't fully solve my problem.
`socket.io` needs nodejs `server` object to listen to it like this. `io.listen(server)`
`mean.io` doesn't provide `server` object atleast I couldn't find it.

I tried to `io.listen(httpServer)` in mean.js and then in my `socket-controller.js` I would simply do

```
io.Socket.on('connection', function(socket){
        socket.emit('message', {'message': 'hello world'});
    });
```

But it didn't works out. My browser keeps on waiting whenever I hit the server.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked into the new package mean.io has come up with socket.io integration? http://mean.io/#!/packages/53e78860fc8c929e0d0a3cc7. This will help you integrate socket.io with mean.io easily.

Comment: I see that that exists, but I can't seem to make anything of it.  Could you provide some more insight?

Answer (score 0):

Install it using **mean install socket**
When installed you should see a page inside with documentation of how to tests it.
Good luck